# Read the entire file into a byte array in WINFORMS

Tags: c#, stream

I want to read the content of the file opened using file dialog box and then save it in a byte array to pass it to a web service

```
        Stream myStream;
        OpenFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "zip files (*.zip)|*.zip|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {

                NSITESERVICE.UploadSoapClient obj = new NSITESERVICE.UploadSoapClient();

                byte[] filebytes =  //what should i pass it over here...

                obj.UploadFile("kamal", "p@ssword", filebytes);

                // Code to write the stream goes here.
                myStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

I dont know where i am wrong

Any help is appreciated. Thnaks

Comment: What should i pass to byte[] filebytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not assigning anything to `filebytes` variable so you are essentially passing null to the service. Use [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) method to read all the bytes and pass it to the webservice.

Comment: Yes i am passing null. Thats my question what should i pass. Please help

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually reading the bytes out of the myStream.

```
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[myStream.Length];
myStream.Read(fileBytes,0,mystream.Length);

obj.UploadFile(...)
```

Comment: That's currently assuming the whole file will be read in a single call. That's a dangerous assumption.

Comment: @KamalDeepSingh: You should either use File.ReadAllBytes, or repeatedly read from the stream and *use the return value from Read* to find out how much was actually read.

Comment: @JonSkeet Just curious, in what instance will a stream returned by the OpenFileDialog not honor the full-length read?

Comment: @jlew: I couldn't say for sure - but *in general* streams shouldn't be assumed to return all their data in one go. The only exception to this rule that I usually allow for is `MemoryStream`. Does `OpenFileDialog` allow you to fetch files from (say) an FTP server mapped into Explorer? If so, that would be a reasonable example of where it may well *not* return all the data in one go. Best not to rely on it either way, IMO.